# Help Identify: 2-player Kingdom building Board Game with role selection

Tags: identify-this-game

This is based off of a review that I remember seeing, and I've never been able to find it again, nor remember its name. I believe that the game was originally Japanese with English rules, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

It was a 2-player duel game where you would have a handful of identical cards that corresponded to worker cards that would grant you various powers. The active player would select three workers and put them face down, then the opposing player would also pick the three roles they thought would be selected. Both players reveal, and if the defending player guessed any workers correctly, the active player doesn't get those cards' powers for the round.

After that, the active player gets the powers of any cards that weren't chosen, gains resources, and can spend them on miscellaneous cards with the end goal to buy two of the three major cards that I think were castles. First player to buy two wins.

There is also one upgraded copy of each of the workers that were available to buy, which would replace the main worker but could still be cancelled by a defender like normal.

Does anyone know which game I'm trying to describe?

Comment: I do not recall the disable part but this look like Settlers of Catan the Card game a bit...

Comment: FYI: [Citadels](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/478/citadels) is a multiplayer version of that to which you can also play 1vs1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some searching on BGG, I think it's **[Greedy Kingdoms](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/57201/greedy-kingdoms)** by [Japon Brand](http://www.japonbrand.com/games2009.html). [AEG mentioned in 2013 that they plan to release it](https://www.alderac.com/biginjapan/), but I don't believe there's been further news of a Western release. The game was restyled and included in the [Princess Wonder](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/152961/princess-wonder) game collection. The English rules can be found [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/48193/rule-english).

As you say, the game is won by building two "Royal Palace" upgrades. There are four resource types: gold, food, honor and land.

Each turn, the current player is the attacker. They may build an upgrade (from the four face-up which replenish, or the pile of three Royal Palaces) or buy a special worker, which replaces and upgrades a basic worker from their hand of eight.

They then battle, secretly selecting three of their eight characters while the defender does the same. The attacker must pay the costs of any matched cards but gains none of their benefits. They then play their unmatched cards, paying the costs and gaining the income.